# String operations in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
Adams   Allen   "prop1-prop2-pro3"
Burns   Bonnie  "prop1Burns-prop2bon-prop3-ch"
Cannon  Charles "prop1a-prop2b-prop3c"
```

I have the above table stored in BigQuery and the 3rd column is guaranteed to have 3 properties separated by '-'.

I want to do string operations on 3rd column and return something like 'custom_string-prop1-custom_string2-prop2' for each row. How do I do in BigQuery?

Comment: so how would output look like based on above input example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split()`:

```
select split('prop1-prop2-pro3', '-')[ordinal(1)] as custom1,
       split('prop1-prop2-pro3', '-')[ordinal(2)] as custom2,
       split('prop1-prop2-pro3', '-')[ordinal(3)] as custom3
```

You can also just put them into an array -- that might be as or more convenient:

```
select split(col, '-') as prop_array
```